# Are all desktop/laptop monitor's orientation similar to landscape orientation on devices like the iPad?

Tags: css, orientation, mobile-safari, media-queries

Are all desktop/laptop monitor's orientation similar to landscape orientation on devices like the iPad?

Is there any difference between?

```
body {background:red}

@media only screen and  (orientation : landscape) {
    body {background:blue}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Are all Desktop/laptop Monitor's orientation similar to Landscape orientation on devices like iPad?

No they are not. The `orientation` is based on the **width and height of the window**.

*Landscape Mode* is when the window width is larger than window height.

*Portrait Mode* is when the window height is larger than window width.

You can see this using your example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/EaHhU/
Adjust the width of the results window to match the above scenarios and you will see the colour change.

Desktop Browser Support: Firefox 3.5+, Google Chrome 5+, Opera 10.6+, Safari 4+

Mobile Browser Support: Android 2+, iOS4, Mobile Firefox.